# Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory using spring boot jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

At first I have a model named person. It worked well and create a table in my database. After I add a new model that have a foreign key to it, I have this problem. I don't have a **dbconfig.java**. I just have a **application.properties**. like this.

```
spring.thymeleaf.mode=LEGACYHTML5


# Database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_example?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# Hibernate
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jackson.serialization.indent-output=true
```

And here are the models

**person.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity 
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@NamedQuery(name="Person.withNameAndcollegeNamedQuery", query = "select p from Person p where p.name=?1 and p.college=?2")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
    private String college;
    private String title;
}
```

**project,java**
    package com.example.model;

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity 
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@NamedQuery(name="Record.withNmaeAndAddressNamedQuery", query = "select p from Record p where p.name=?1 and address=?2")
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String projectName;
    @OneToOne
    private Person person;
    private String description;
    private Subject subject;
    private String date;
}
```

And this is the console log:

```
13:30:30.244 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
13:30:30.247 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
13:30:30.248 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/E:/workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE/demo/target/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)

2017-08-11 13:30:30.474  INFO 12108 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.DemoApplication              : Starting DemoApplication on MoriatyC with PID 12108 (E:\workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE\demo\target\classes started by cmh in E:\workspace-sts-3.8.4.RELEASE\demo)
2017-08-11 13:30:30.475  INFO 12108 --- [  restartedMain] com.example.DemoApplication              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-08-11 13:30:30.652  INFO 12108 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@2350e3c9: startup date [Fri Aug 11 13:30:30 CST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-11 13:30:32.149  INFO 12108 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-08-11 13:30:32.157  INFO 12108 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-08-11 13:30:32.158  INFO 12108 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
2017-08-11 13:30:32.230  INFO 12108 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-08-11 13:30:32.230  INFO 12108 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1580 ms
2017-08-11 13:30:32.350  INFO 12108 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-08-11 13:30:32.353  INFO 12108 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-11 13:30:32.353  INFO 12108 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-11 13:30:32.353  INFO 12108 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-11 13:30:32.354  INFO 12108 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-11 13:30:32.806  INFO 12108 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-08-11 13:30:32.820  INFO 12108 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-08-11 13:30:32.954  INFO 12108 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-08-11 13:30:32.955  INFO 12108 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-08-11 13:30:32.956  INFO 12108 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-08-11 13:30:32.988  INFO 12108 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-08-11 13:30:33.074  INFO 12108 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
2017-08-11 13:30:33.232  WARN 12108 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
2017-08-11 13:30:33.237  INFO 12108 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-08-11 13:30:33.249  INFO 12108 --- [  restartedMain] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-08-11 13:30:33.257 ERROR 12108 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.6.RELEASE.jar:1.5.6.RELEASE]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:954) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:882) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.example.model.Subject, at table: project, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(subject)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:398) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:595) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you have to create a `Subject` entity and map it to your `Projects` entity with `@OneToOne`

Add

```
@OneToOne
    private Subject subject;
```

in your **Project.java** file.

**Subject.java**

```
package com.example.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Subject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    //Other fields according to your need and setter/getter

}
```

After creating the `Subject` entity you get an error in your `Project` entity at `@NamedQuery` line so you have to change your named query like below (you can change fields according to your need)

```
@NamedQuery(name="Project.withProjectNameAndDescriptionQuery", query = "select p from Project p where p.projectName=?1 and p.description=?2")
```

Answer (score 1):

then problem is `Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.example.model.Subject, at table: project, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(subject)]`. you are using `private Subject subject;` into `Project` entity, and the column name `Subject` is not determining. so if `Subject` entity is present into your entity package the you need to `@JoinColumn(name = "SUBJECT_ID")` or you can also use another column for mapping.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CITY_ID")
private Subject subject;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a mapping exception. You are using a field `subject` in your `Person` Entity which is of `Subject` class.

Hibernate cannot map a field with a complex type to a simple column. It has to be an entity defined and mapped.

So, to solve your problem, define the class `Subject` as an entity, map it to your probably already existing Subject table in DB, and then specify the relationship between `Person` and `Subject` by annotating the field `subject` with the appropriate annotation (`@ManyToOne` or `@OneToOne`) and any `@JoinColumn` necessary.

By the way I would recommend to define your mapping columns explicitly (annotation `@Column` if Hibernate doesn't generate the schema. That will allow you to change your variable names without need to change database column names